# Drag only origin or destination of route

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working on project with google maps api v3. I need to create route from two points which I can drag. I am using this code (without waypoints):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

But is possible allow dragging only origin point and destination point? Because I don't want change route between origin point and destination point.

Comment: question is different but code in question is exactly what I need.

Comment: @marek, I'm also voting to close as a duplicate, so that this can act as a signpost to that question (it gets a nice banner at the top).